# Clean Install of 18.04 server does not mount all partitions

Tags: server, 18.04, fstab

After a failed update from 16.04 server to 18.04, I did a fresh install of 18.04 server. When checking fstab I see that not all partitions are mounted.

Here's the `fstab` entries:

```
UUID=bce7a885-a404-11e8-ad4b-002564c498c6 / ext4 defaults  0 0
UUID=bce7a884-a404-11e8-ad4b-002564c498c6 /boot ext4 defaults 0 0
```

And the results of `blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: PARTUUID="740e4ad7-d889-41ce-88f8-4155d1694705"    
/dev/sda2: UUID="bce7a884-a404-11e8-ad4b-002564c498c6" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="64b156ac-763c-4f99-a35d-926f1bae1e4d"    
/dev/sda3: UUID="Y2eQMg-gI24-76bI-BITG-OBhP-MVln-LOn3eJ" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="e94a812a-b343-43fc-b8ab-aa2cc601bf4b"
```

The results of `fdisk -l`

```
Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type    
/dev/sda1     2048       4095       2048     1M BIOS boot    
/dev/sda2     4096    2101247    2097152     1G Linux filesystem    
/dev/sda3  2101248 1953521663 1951420416 930.5G Linux filesystem
```

The fstab is very different from what I saw in 16.04. I am no expert and need any help I can get on this one.

I have tried to add entries in `fstab` but get errors

```
ex: fstab -/dev/sda3 /home/tom/temp  auto defaults   0   0 

result - mount: /home/tom/temp: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member
```